# How does the bottom op amp work in this schematic?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I have this circuit that I am trying to analyze but can't see how it would work. It has two inputs but no feedback in the circuit. Can anyone help me figure this circuit out? The circuit I am trying to understand is the purpose of the U1A.

Thanks!

Updated drawing - hopefully this helps.

[image]

Comment: I can see a .1nF capacitor doing negative feedback there. What is the full circuit doing?

Comment: Can you provide a better question than, "can you help me figure this out?" What is it exactly that you are looking for?

Comment: @VoltageSpike. I am trying to figure out how the bottom amplifier on the left works. I tried to simulate it and it just goes to its negative voltage rail

Comment: Great, can you edit the question and include that?

Answer (score 3):

The circuit is an integrator, possible part of a control loop for something downstream.  There are two negative feedback paths.

C5 is the integrator capacitor.  The time constant is C5 x (R9||Rg3).  This assumes that U1D is configured as a voltage amplifier with a low output impedance.

The second feedback path is through U1D and Rg3.  If there is a DC feedback path, this is it.  We don't know enough about the rest of the circuit to say what that path is doing, but there probably is a non-inverting signal path from the right side of R10, around to the output of U1D.

Comment: Yes - it should be emphasized that the integrator stage would not work as desired without a stabilizing DC negative feedback path.